# write the image to outputStream and not a file to update the entity in the database

Tags: java

The byte[] content is the content of the image in the database. So after getting it I am checking its size and in case of size of 2MB I am compressing it then I want to update the entity in the database.
Currently I am able to write the compressed image as a jpg file. How can write the image as Outputstream without the need of  `compressedImageFile`? Then I want to convert it to byte array and update the entity in the database.

```
private void compressImage(byte[] content){
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(content);
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(inputStream);

        Iterator<ImageWriter> writers = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg");
        ImageWriter imageWriter = writers.next();
        //With this two lines I can write the content to the file.
        //File compressedImageFile = new File("C:\\Users\\photos\\temp\\image.jpg");        
        //OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(compressedImageFile);

        //OutputStream os = new OutputStream();
        ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(os);
        imageWriter.setOutput(ios);
        getLogger().info("ios: " + ios);

        ImageWriteParam param = imageWriter.getDefaultWriteParam();
        if (param.canWriteCompressed()) {
            System.out.println("Yes it can write compress!");
            param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
            String[] types = param.getCompressionTypes();
            param.setCompressionQuality(0.5f);
            System.out.println("canWriteCompressed is true");

        }

        imageWriter.write(null, new IIOImage(image, null, null), param);
        getLogger().info("ios at the end: " + ios);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: You *maybe* are looking for https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html

Comment: Most image types are already compressed so I guess you mean reduce the image quality to reduce the file size? Maybe you need an API that manipulate images.

Comment: How did you get it *out* of the database, and how is it represented *in* the database?